# SQLAlchemy and flask relationships

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

UPDATE:  Thanks to one of the comments I got closer, I did add the association table:

```
association = db.Table('association',
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), primary_key=True),
    db.Column('restaraunt_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('restaraunt.id'), primary_key=True)
)
```

It worked pretty good, in the shell i was able to:

```
u=User(username='bob', email='bob@villa.com')
db.session.add(u)
db.session.commit()
r=Restaraunt(name='Five Guys', costRating=4)
db.session.add(r)
db.session.commit()
rp=RestarauntPreferences(user=u, restaraunt=r, rating=0)
db.session.add(rp)
db.session.commit()
```

Then:

```
rp.restaraunt.name
['Five Guys']
```

AWESOME.   BUT... the db.session.add(rp) adds duplicate entries into the RestarauntPreferences table?  Something with how I declared the association?   Something else I am not getting about SQLAlchemy and flask?
(And using db browser to look at the sqlite database, the association table has no information in it after I run the shell commands, not sure if this is correct... or not?)

ORIG POST: (Models below)

I was trying to build this little flask app that uses SQLAlchemy.  The models I am trying to work with and work relationships with are many-to-many.   They are described below with how I want to use them.

(Essentially a user can give a rating to multiple restaurants)

```
#how do I use these??

rprefs=RestarauntPreferences.query.filter_by(user=current_user) 
rprefs.restaraunt.name   #doesn't work, doesn't know what restaraunt is

#models below

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    password_hash = db.Column(db.String(128))
    recipient_idf= db.Column(db.String(256))
    first_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    last_name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    most_recent_lunch_date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    lunch_Rating = db.Column(db.Integer)
    phone_number = db.Column(db.String(128))

    def set_password(self, password):
        self.password_hash = generate_password_hash(password)

    def check_password(self, password):
        return check_password_hash(self.password_hash, password)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User {} {}>'.format(self.username, self.recipient_idf)


class Restaraunt(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'restaraunt'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
    costRating = db.Column(db.Integer)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Restaraunt {} {}>'.format(self.name, self.costRating)


class RestarauntPreferences(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'restaraunt_preferences'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    restaraunt_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('restaraunt.id'))
    restaraunt = relationship("Restaraunt", foreign_keys=[restaraunt_id])

    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship("User", foreign_keys=[user_id])

    rating = db.Column(db.Integer)


    def __repr__(self):
        return '<RestarauntPref {} {} {}>'.format(self.restaraunt_id, self.user_id, self.rating)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both, [Flask-Sqlalchemy](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/models/#many-to-many-relationships) and [Sqlalchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many), documentations state that an association table required for a many-to-many relationship to work. Try creating it like in examples and add to your declaration as a `secondary` param.

Comment: I saw the associations in the documentation but I felt that I didn't want to use that or need that as I the RestarauntPreferences table was an association with the rating.  I just don't see how the associations table they recommend also can connect the rating information as well.  I haven't made that aha moment with that I guess.

Comment: you mentioned the secondary argument, so I tried to add that under the RestarauntPrefs under reach relationship where secondary=association, it lets me create the DB but running any code complains right away that it could not determine the join condition between parent child on relationship RestarauntPreferences.restaraunt, says no foreign keys but I clearly have them declared?

Comment: Finally freaking got it thanks for having me take another look, the secondary tip was the key.